# new to android and java - why is newInstance(String prompt) being used

Tags: java, android

please look at the following snippet of code:

```
public class PromptDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private EditText et;

    public static PromptDialogFragment
    newInstance(String prompt)
    {
        PromptDialogFragment pdf = new PromptDialogFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("prompt",prompt);
        pdf.setArguments(bundle);

        return pdf;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity act) {
```

I am not sure what newInstance(String prompt) does here nor why it is being used.. 
I am going to guess that it is to start a new instance of the PromptDialogFragment class?

But if that is true, then it seems unnecessary because a new instance is already being invoked here:

```
PromptDialogFragment pdf = 
PromptDialogFragment.newInstance(
"Enter Something");
pdf.show(ft, PROMPT_DIALOG_TAG);
```

Comment: Remove it and see if it makes any difference? Then you will know what is doing there.

Comment: but you are also passing a string and you can't create a constructor with params for fragment

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snipped has declaration of method that creates new instance of the class. While the second snippet actually invokes (calls) previously declared method.

This approach can be used to create new instance of the class and initialize it in a custom way.